# MongoDB aggregation sum values and group by property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that looks like this

```
{
 balance: string
 symbol: string
 address: string
}
```

I want to query that collection using an aggregation as following:

```
input array addresses[]
```

query collection where collection.address contained in provided address Array and SUM all balances grouped by symbol.

The desired output should look like this:

```
[
  {symbol: xy, balance: summedBalanceForThisSymbol},
  {symbol: yz, balance: summedBalanceForThisSymbol},
]
```

I am rather new to mongoDB, this is what I have which doesnt work at all.

```
  const pipe = [
        {
            match: [
                {
                    address: { $in: addresses } //addresses is an array of string values
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            group: {
                objectId: "$symbol",
                balance: { $sum: "$balance" }
            }
        }
    ]
```

I have to use objectId instead of _id because the SDK I am using requires to do so. I also need the string balance values to be converted to a number (I guess double) before summing up.

Comment: what do you mean by `input array addresses[]`?

Comment: the function that fires the query has an argument of type string array.

Comment: it's important to separate out anything unrelated to the question to prevent confusion. so if i understood you right you want to filter by a string-array right? also it is unclear where exactly you are struggling (filtering or grouping)

Comment: my example aggregation structure should clarify what I am intending to do, also I described in initial post my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, you just have some minor syntax errors, this is how you should do it:

(One thing to mentioned is this requires `balance` to be a valid number string, if not the pipeline will throw an error)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      address: {
        $in: addresses
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$symbol",
      sum: {
        $sum: {
          "$toInt": "$balance"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2r5g5Jxp390)